# MariaDB restart restart unexpectedly

Tags: mariadb

I've got a problem on my MariaDB server, it sometimes restart randomly (thus causing the different apps using the database to crash).
I'm using MariaDB 10.5.13 on a Debian 9.13 LXC container.
Here's an extract from the log files at the moment of a crash

```
2021-12-08 15:31:08 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery from checkpoint LSN=136812498411,136812498411
2021-12-08 15:31:08 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting final batch to recover 959 pages from redo log.
2021-12-08 15:31:13 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segments are active.
2021-12-08 15:31:13 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2021-12-08 15:31:13 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2021-12-08 15:31:13 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2021-12-08 15:31:13 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2021-12-08 15:31:13 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.5.13 started; log sequence number 136845071206; transaction id 181627447
2021-12-08 15:31:13 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
2021-12-08 15:31:13 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2021-12-08 15:31:13 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2021-12-08 15:31:13 0 [Note] Reading of all Master_info entries succeeded
2021-12-08 15:31:13 0 [Note] Added new Master_info '' to hash table
2021-12-08 15:31:13 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mariadbd: ready for connections.
2021-12-08 15:31:13 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 211208 15:31:13
2021-12-08 15:31:22 25 [Warning] Aborted connection 25 to db: 'unconnected' user: 'unauthenticated' host: 'localhost' (This connection closed normally without authentication)
2021-12-08 15:36:05 687 [Warning] Aborted connection 687 to db: 'unconnected' user: 'unauthenticated' host: 'localhost' (This connection closed normally without authentication)
2021-12-08 15:41:08 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2021-12-08 15:41:08 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
2021-12-08 15:41:08 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2021-12-08 15:41:08 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using crc32 + pclmulqdq instructions
2021-12-08 15:41:08 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2021-12-08 15:41:08 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 134217728, chunk size = 134217728
2021-12-08 15:41:08 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2021-12-08 15:41:08 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery from checkpoint LSN=136812498411,136812498411
2021-12-08 15:41:08 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting final batch to recover 1117 pages from redo log.
2021-12-08 15:41:12 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segments are active.
2021-12-08 15:41:13 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2021-12-08 15:41:13 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2021-12-08 15:41:13 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2021-12-08 15:41:13 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2021-12-08 15:41:13 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.5.13 started; log sequence number 136864854170; transaction id 181644325
2021-12-08 15:41:13 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
2021-12-08 15:41:13 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2021-12-08 15:41:13 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2021-12-08 15:41:13 0 [Note] Reading of all Master_info entries succeeded
2021-12-08 15:41:13 0 [Note] Added new Master_info '' to hash table
2021-12-08 15:41:13 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mariadbd: ready for connections.
2021-12-08 15:41:13 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 211208 15:41:13
2021-12-08 15:41:22 23 [Warning] Aborted connection 23 to db: 'unconnected' user: 'unauthenticated' host: 'localhost' (This connection closed normally without authentication)
2021-12-08 15:45:50 263 [Warning] Aborted connection 263 to db: 'unconnected' user: 'unauthenticated' host: 'localhost' (This connection closed normally without authentication)
2021-12-08 15:51:04 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2021-12-08 15:51:04 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
2021-12-08 15:51:04 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2021-12-08 15:51:04 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using crc32 + pclmulqdq instructions
2021-12-08 15:51:04 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2021-12-08 15:51:04 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 134217728, chunk size = 134217728
2021-12-08 15:51:04 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2021-12-08 15:51:04 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery from checkpoint LSN=136812498411,136812498411
```

Would anyone have recommandations to tackle this problem ?

Thanks,

Edit : I paste the full logs between two crashes. I don't know what the aborted connections are given that I only use this DB server from clients on other container, not on localhost.

Edit 2 : Here's a link to download the whole file :
https://cloud.ei-bs.eu/index.php/s/NsMjezd3mB25AAY

Comment: The log content is not from moment of crash, but from moment of restarting the server (InnoDB crash recovery is performed during initialization of MariaDB server).

Comment: Sorry, I edited the question with the full logs between two crashes.

Comment: Log is still incomplete.

Comment: I added a link to download the log file I retrieved on the server.